# Rails 4 Capybara + Selenium, Data-confirm

Tags: selenium, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, rspec-rails

I have this problem with my code.This page inside my application is using http basic authentication. I'm testing my application with Rspec and Capybara, but I have problem with data confirmation when deleting comment, it just can't seem to pass.

Here is my test code:

```
   before(:each) do
     page.driver.browser.authorize ENV['ADMIN_LOGIN'], ENV['ADMIN_PASSWORD']
     ...
   end

  ...

  it "should redirect to create new inspiring post and create new post on click" do
    visit admin_path
    click_link("create_inspi")
    fill_in("Title",:with => "Test title")
    fill_in("Short",:with => "Test short desc")
    fill_in("Body",:with => "Test body desc")
    fill_in("Date",:with => "12.12.2012")
    click_button("Create new post")
    test(
      have_content("Test title"),
      have_content("12.12.2012")
    )
  end

  example "when inside Link to all... you can delete particular comment",:js => true do
    visit admin_path
    click_link("Link to all comments in Web development and Motivation category")
    click_link(@webdev_comment.id)
    page.driver.browser.accept_js_confirms
  end
```

Now for my test by default I use Capybara::RackTest::Driver, but now since I can't find a way to confirm data confirmation with RackTest I have to use Selenium driver to make this data confirmed. But now when using this Selenium driver for my last example test I found next problem:

```
  1) testing admin webpage when inside Link to all... you can delete particular comment
     Failure/Error: page.driver.browser.authorize ENV['ADMIN_LOGIN'], ENV['ADMIN_PASSWORD']
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authorize' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x00000003e6ad68>
     # ./spec/features/admin.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

MY QUESTION IS:

How to authenticate basic http with selenium?

-------------- EDITED ------------------

I found a way to log in into admin with selenium driver by using this code

```
example "when inside Link to all... you can delete particular comment",:js => true do
    visit root_path
    @url = current_url
    @tablica = @url.split("http://")
    @correct_url = @tablica[1]
    admin_selenium_path = "http://#{ENV["ADMIN_LOGIN"]}:#{ENV["ADMIN_PASSWORD"]}@#{@correct_url}admin"
    page.visit admin_selenium_path
    click_link("Link to all comments in Web development and Motivation category")
    click_link(@webdev_comment.id)
    page.driver.browser.accept_js_confirms
end
```

But now , even though it's logging in , there is literally no data inside test database, and it's throwing errors around saying that particular object couldn't be found.

```
before(:each) do
   # page.driver.browser.authorize ENV['ADMIN_LOGIN'], ENV['ADMIN_PASSWORD']
   @mystory = Mystory.create(name: "My story:",body: "My name is Matthew...")
end
```

This code above inside before block is not creating a required @mystory record inside database for capybara with selenium driver.

Any ideas how to populate database for capybara with selenium driver?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's exactly the same issue but I add this somewhere above/before to skip over confirm dialogs with Capybara

```
page.evaluate_script('window.confirm = function() { return true; }')
```

Comment: Are you adding it before the confirm appears? Rather than after? If it is after, then it won't work. It must be done before (even on the first line of the test)

Comment: I was adding it in before block and it's not working.

Comment: It can't be in the before block, because page isn't a valid page then. In fact it can't be on the first line either, it needs to be the line after 'visit root_path', or after 'page.visit admin_selenium_path'.

Comment: Once you have visited a new url, then page object is the new page. So the execution of the script I gave must be run on the relevant 'page'

Comment: I don't know if we understand each other correctly, I have problem right now with populating test database for capybara + selenium. I just made it yesterday and I logged in with basic http auth with this code that you can see above, and I also know that my code that I'm using to confirm data deletion is also working because I tested it in my production environment and it was confirming deletion. Now I have problem with populating my test database with records, because selenium doesn't seem to populate database with records seen inside let() or before block.